# Dynamically inserting content within same page rather then going to a new page

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-mobile

**EDIT** *italics* = more detailed explanation added to the question. Thanks.

I'm building a jQuery Mobile site which has a Gallery section.
The gallery has a series of thumbnails on the top of the screen.
Users click on the thumbnail to *load in new content, that being a larger image, text, and potentially audio on some of them*.

It's at this point that I'm not sure what to do: the way jQuery Mobile works, it's geared towards loading new pages, or views. But I just want to inject new content in a container on the ***current*** page.

To be clear, when the user clicks on another thumbnail, a new image replaces the content of the container with new content.

I have two questions:
I'm not sure how to structure the dynamic content. I was thinking i'd create an html file for each item, which as a rule always contains a title, information and sometimes, audio.

I'm not sure how to script this functionality in jQuery Mobile. It's obviously Ajax, but I'm not familiar with it yet, especially since jQuery Mobile has it's own methods in place already which seems to redefine behaviors in a way that's contradictory to this approach described here.

*Here is a code explanation of what i'm trying to do:*

```
    <!-- Galleries -->
    <div data-role="page" id="galleries">
        <div data-role="content" role="main">
            This is the Selection UI, if i click on thumb2.jpg, it'd 
            fill #content-holder with the whatever html is in content2.php
            <div id="thumb-carousel">
                <a href="content1.php"><img src="thumb1.jpg"></a>
                <a href="content2.php"><img src="thumb2.jpg"></a>
                <a href="content3.php"><img src="thumb3.jpg"></a>
                <a href="content4.php"><img src="thumb4.jpg"></a>
                <a href="content5.php"><img src="thumb5.jpg"></a>
                <a href="content6.php"><img src="thumb6.jpg"></a>
                <a href="content7.php"><img src="thumb7.jpg"></a>
                <a href="content8.php"><img src="thumb8.jpg"></a>
                <a href="content9.php"><img src="thumb9.jpg"></a>
            </div>
            <!-- This is the container, currently it's filled
            with the kinda stuff i need to put in it. -->
            <div id="content-holder">
                <img src="myimage1.jpg"/>
                <p>Artwork Title</p>
                <p>Caption</p>
                <audio>//mp3</audio>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you only loading an image or an image and image title/information?

Comment: I'm loading an image with title, caption and potentially an audio file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//remember to use event delegation because you never know when the page will be in the DOM
$(document).delegate('#galleries', 'pageinit', function () {

    //bind a `click` event handler to each thumbnail link
    $('#thumb-carousel').children().bind('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url     : $(this).attr('href'),
            success : function (serverResponse) {

                //select the container,
                //then fade it out,
                //change it's HTML to the response from the AJAX request,
                //and fade it back in
                $('#content-holder').fadeOut(500, function () {
                    $(this).html(serverResponse).fadeIn(500);
                });
            },
            error   : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //remember to handle errors so your page doesn't seem broken to the user
            }
        });

        //prevent the default behavior of the link, which is to navigate to the `href` attribute
        return false;
    });
});
```

This expects your server-response to be valid HTML markup that is ready to inject into the DOM, meaning no `<html>` or `<body>` tags, just what you want to add to the DOM:

```
<img src="..." />
<span>TITLE</span>
<audio src="..."></audio>
```

Here are some docs for ya:

- `$.ajax()`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax
- `.closest()`: http://api.jquery.com/closest
- `.fadeIn()`: http://api.jquery.com/fadein

Comment: Thanks for this thorough answer. I'm a little unsure of how to id and class my elements based on this JS. Would it be something to the effect of for the thumbnail carousel: <div class="allthumbnails"><a href="*content file*"><thumbnail /></a></div> and then the div that will house the dynamically inserted content: <div class="parent-container">[dynamic content will go here]</div> ? Also i'm unsure what *#gallery-page-id* represents. Sorry for being such a newbie :-/

Comment: @RGBK Check-out the **update** to my answer. `#gallery-page-id` refers to the ID of the `data-role="page"` element for this pseudo-page.

Comment: Sorry my question was perhaps not clear, I've **updated** it for you extensively above... but does the *example HTML structure* in your update represent the markup found within the external html file that will be pulled into the content holder? If that's the case, i'd have assumed this would just do what jQuery Mobile always does, it'd just animate to it as if it's a new page. It also conflicts then with the initial markup you'd written in the first edit. I'm also confused as the script is not looking for a link to do stuff with so how can it pull new content in? Thank you again.

Comment: @RGBK **1)** I updated my answer to reflect your HTML structure. **2)** If you hijack the link clicks you can prevent the default behavior (which in this case would be for jQuery Mobile to hijack the link clicks), which is what my code above does. **3)** My code *was* binding to elements with the `.thumbnail-image` class since I didn't know your actual markup (I thought that seemed semantically logical). **4)** Anyway, check-out the update, it should get ya going.